# Problem rising spring batch version 3.0.7 to 3.0.9

Tags: java, maven, spring-batch

I am working on a Java project using the Spring Batch framework and I have to upgrade it from version 3.0.7 to 3.0.9 but I have a problem :

```
@Bean
public Step bonjourRetourJpaToX(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
        ItemProcessor<BonjourRetourGroup, BonjourElementBlocAgent> compBonjourRetourBonjourProcessor,
        @Qualifier("promotionListenerBonjourRetour") ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListenerBonjourRetour) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("bonjourRetourJpaToX").<BonjourRetourGroup, BonjourElementBlocAgent>chunk(batchSizeLoadXml)
            .reader(bonjourRetourJpaReader)
            .processor(compBonjourRetourBonjourProcessor)
            .writer(bonjourRetourXmlWriter)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .listener(promotionListenerBonjourRetour)
            .listener(dsBonjourRetourFinalProcessor())
            .listener(dsBonjourRetourTemporaryProcessor)
            .listener(bonjourRetourBonjourBoucleStepListener())
            .throttleLimit(bonjourRetourJobThrottleLimit)
            .build();
}
```

With the maven compilation error :

> [ERROR] src/main/java/source/bonjourRetour/batch/BonjourRetourJobConfig.java:[1025,33] cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   method throttleLimit(int)

This step is multi-threaded

Comment: Do you have the problem with version 3.0.8?

Comment: I don't have the problem with the version 3.0.8

Comment: Interesting! Could you please share a project with the minimal code that works with 3.0.7 but not with 3.0.9? I will take care of the investigation to see if there is a regression. Thanks upfront.

Answer (score 0):

For Mahmoud Ben Hassine :

The composite processor ->

```
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.NO)
@Bean(name = "compBonjourRetourBonjourProcessorX")
public ItemProcessor<BonjourRetourGroup, XElementBlocAgent> compBonjourRetourBonjourProcessorX(@Value("#{stepExecution}") final StepExecution stepExecution) {
    CompositeItemProcessor<BonjourRetourGroup, XElementBlocAgent> compositeProcessor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();

    compositeProcessor
            .setDelegates(Arrays.asList(dsBonjourRetourXTemporaryProcessor, dsBonjourRetourXinalProcessor()));
    return compositeProcessor;
}
```

I noticed that when I moved the listener : bonjourRetourBonjourBoucleStepListener(); like that it compiles :

```
 @Bean
 public Step bonjourRetourJpaToX(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, TaskExecutor 
 taskExecutor,
    ItemProcessor<BonjourRetourGroup, BonjourElementBlocAgent> compBonjourRetourBonjourProcessor,
    @Qualifier("promotionListenerBonjourRetour") ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListenerBonjourRetour) {
return stepBuilderFactory.get("bonjourRetourJpaToX").<BonjourRetourGroup, BonjourElementBlocAgent>chunk(batchSizeLoadXml)
        .reader(bonjourRetourJpaReader)
        .processor(compBonjourRetourBonjourProcessor)
        .writer(bonjourRetourXmlWriter)
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
        .listener(promotionListenerBonjourRetour)
        .listener(dsBonjourRetourFinalProcessor())
        .listener(bonjourRetourBonjourBoucleStepListener())
        //SWITCHED
        .listener(dsBonjourRetourTemporaryProcessor)
        .throttleLimit(bonjourRetourJobThrottleLimit)
        .build();
```

I know that dsBonjourRetourTemporaryProcessor return an ItemProcessor and bonjourRetourBonjourBoucleStepListener return a StepExecutionListener

For the other parts of my project with this problem, when I moved a StepExecutionListener, it works

Maybe the problem is here ?

Comment: Thanks for the updates. This is tricky because there are multiple overloaded `listener` methods in these builders. One of them `AbstractTaskletStepBuilder#listener(java.lang.Object)` returns the current builder type, that's why the order of calling listeners may be important. But I don't know which combination leads to the method `throttleLimit` being not visible. I would love to help but I need the full code of a minimal sample to reproduce the issue (for example, I can't know, just by looking at your example, which builder type is returned by `.listener(promotionListenerBonjourRetour)`).

Comment: Thanks you for the help Mahmoud. The .listener(promotionListenerBonjourRetour) return a 
org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ExecutionContextPromotionListener
I'm sorry for the few information but I'm working on a confidential project and I can't give the source of the project :(